# columns names does not change while selecting count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, alias

I'm selecting count from multiple tables but the columns' names does not change though using As clause here's the code

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM  new_cards WHERE Bill_ID = '584762578412569') AS newcards,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM  sold_cards WHERE Bill_ID = '584762578412569') AS soldcards
```

I get 2 columns and their names are `COUNT(ID)` both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query assigns aliases to the sub-queries (table aliases) not the columns. Moving the alias to the **column** should fix it:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(ID) AS newcards FROM  new_cards WHERE Bill_ID = '584762578412569') n,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) AS soldcards FROM  sold_cards WHERE Bill_ID = '584762578412569') s
```